# Enum programatic access for tuple value

Tags: python, enums, enumeration

I have following code:

```
class TupleEnum(Enum):
    def __new__(cls, first_value, second_value):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = first_value
        obj._second_value = second_value

        return obj

    @DynamicClassAttribute
    def value(self):
        return self._value_

    @DynamicClassAttribute
    def second_value(self):
        return self._second_value


class ExampleEnum(TupleEnum):
    RED = "red", "Red"


ExampleEnum["RED"]
ExampleEnum(("red", "Red"))  # doesn't trigger error but I wanna use just `red` 
ExampleEnum("red")  # Causes error
```

I'd like to be able to access enum member by its value (which in my case is first element of the tuple)

How is it possible?

Comment: `DynamicClassAttribute` to which package belongs to?

Comment: from types import DynamicClassAttribute

Comment: Maybe you have to look into the EnumMeta metaclass that Enum class use to build new Enum classes, becouse what you are really doing when you do `ExampleEnum("red")` is calling the `__call__` in the metaclass

Comment: The code you have posted is not the code you tested with.  The code you posted fails on the second example and passes the third.  Also, did you mean to also subclass `tuple`?